# .htaccess going to the wrong file, queries are being lost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Basically I had my website on another server originally and all the .htaccess worked fine - We then transferred the server to our new server and the phpinfo() commands runs almost the exact same settings.

We have a url structure like this for example;

```
http://example.org/tag/example+tag
```

and we have the same sort of structure for our search for example;

```
http://exampe.org/search?search=search+term
```

However, for some mad crazy reason when you go to the tag url it's going to the search page.. Here is our .htaccess;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^login login.php
RewriteRule ^register register.php
RewriteRule ^dashboard dashboard.php
RewriteRule ^addserver addserver.php
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ searchtag.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search search.php
RewriteRule ^ad/(.*)$ cron_servers_banners.php?server=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^list/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) list.php?page=$1 
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)$ serveredit.php?sid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)$ serverpage.php?sid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)/remove$ serverpage.php?sid=$1&remove=yes [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)/cremove$ serverpage.php?sid=$1&cremove=yes [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)/favourite$ serverpage.php?sid=$1&favourite=yes [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)/unfavourite$ serverpage.php?sid=$1&unfavourite=yes [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sponsor/(.*)$ sponsor.php?sid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^history/(.*)$ serverhistory.php?sid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^vote/(.*)$ servervote.php?sid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lost lost.php
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ searchtag.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]` this checks for `tag/sometag`, if it exists, it forwards it to `searchtag.php?=sometag`..

Comment: So from what you are saying @Ohgodwhy, it's correct? Then how come it always forwards it to search.php?

Comment: because `search` can be found in `searchtag` and your RewriteRule checks for `search` but never stops by calling `$` or identifying a `/` (trailing slash)

Comment: Okay so I have to finish each rule by adding `$` at the end of them? So if I change the search tag to this: `search$ search.php` it should work?

Comment: In fact, I've decided against advising to use a `$` to declare the end of the expression in your case. please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you're redirecting `/tag/sometag` to `searchtag.php?tag=sometag`.

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ searchtag.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, you have another existing rule that says, "match anything that starts with search"

```
RewriteRule ^search search.php
```

Because `search` is part of `searchtag` you must add a trailing `/`.

```
RewriteRule ^search/ search.php
```

Comment: Oh.. I see now.. Okay so I added `$` at the end of `RewriteRule ^search$ search.php` because I use the `$_GET` form to search. Anywho. So why is it when I go to the url `http://example.org/server/1/favourite` it doesn't work?

Comment: @Scott I have no idea what you're asking there. Did you go and add a `$` to the end of every rule? I didn't advise you to do that if you did. Revert that change and only make the change that I mentioned above. Also, it should be `^server/(.*)/(.*)$` in this particular case you're talking about.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I have reverted the change. Okay, so I have changed what you said to: `RewriteRule ^server/(.*)/(.*)$ serverpage.php?sid=$1&option=$2 [NC,L]` Although when I go to the url and try and echo option, nothing shows? @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Scott You'll need to look at the error logs. Something is wrong with your .htaccess file.

Comment: @Scott Seems like an unrelated issue. I'd recommend making a new question if general debugging doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: I actually just figured out why, I moved the `RewriteRule ^server/(.*)$ serverpage.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]` below the other rules and it seems to have worked. I'm guessing it takes priority if it's higher? - Thank you in advance for the help. @Ohgodwhy